# How to find Distinct No of Document on specific field MongoDB and Implement in Java

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, aggregation-framework

I have data and need to group by two fields and in response display unique filed along with the count on this field.

**Sample data:**

```
[
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName1",
      "cat_id": "A"
   },
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName1",
      "cat_id": "B"
   },
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode2",
      "categoryName":"categoryName2",
      "cat_id": "C"
   }
]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName1",
      "cat_count": 2
   },
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode2",
      "categoryName":"categoryName2",
      "cat_count": 1
   }
]
```

and how to implement it in Java with Aggregation Object.

```java
GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group("categoryCode", "categoryName").sum(1).as("cat_count");
```

but getting compile error:

> 1 is not taken inside sum method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$group` - Group by `categoryCode` and `categoryName`. And add aggregate field `cat_count` for `$sum` when match with group.
2. `$project` - Display document for desired output field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "categoryCode": "$categoryCode",
        "categoryName": "$categoryName"
      },
      "cat_count": {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "categoryCode": "$_id.categoryCode",
      "categoryName": "$_id.categoryName",
      "cat_count": "$cat_count"
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XsXbWECZ5Tl)